# importing a .txt file into a .dat cplex opl

Tags: text, cplex, instances, opl

In an optimization problem I need to open my data for the problem in the .dat file. The problem is that the data is in a text file (notebook) and I don't know how I should connect it and work with a lot of instances. Could someone help me? I am searching for it, but I cannot find something that explains clearly.

Comment: The .dat file format that is used by CPLEX is just a text file format. If you want to use the .dat format files, you will probably need to edit your text files manually. Have a look at some examples in the CPLEX examples directory and/or read the documentation. You may be better off reading the data from the text files into a database (e.g. SQL Server) or a spreadsheet and then reading the data direct from there with CPLEX.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your file in notepad
2. Go to Save As
3. Type yourfilename.dat (without space). You should put .dat extension manually
4. Save

Answer (score 0):

You can read from a text file in cplex like:

```
execute //you should write this code in an execute block
{
   var fileID= new IloOplInputFile("fileName.txt");
   var contenct = fileID.readline();
   var intContenct = Opl.intValue(contenct); //in case you want to convert what you read into an integer value
   fileID.clos();
}
```